# Чтение string из бинарного файла при помощи QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

Осваиваю qt, нужно реализовать запись структуры worker из текстовых полей в бинарный файл workers.dat а затем считать все записи из этого файла и вывести в MessageBox в порядке возрастания wsalary

```
    #include <QFile>
    #include <QDataStream>
    #include <QMessageBox>

    using namespace std;

    const char FName[] = "workers.dat";

    struct worker{
        string wname;
        string wlastname;
        int wsalary;
    };

    QDataStream &operator >> (QDataStream &stream, const worker &A) {
        stream >> A.wname; //invalid operands to binary expression('QDataSDtream' and 'const std::string')

        stream >> A.wlastname;//invalid operands to binary expression('QDataSDtream' and 'const std::string')

        stream >> A.wsalary//invalid operands to binary expression('QDataSDtream' and 'const std::string')
    }

    void MainWindow::on_ReadFilepushButton_clicked()
    {
        worker man;
        QString s = "";
        QFile file (FName);
        QDataStream stream(&file);

        file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);

        //записать в цикле содержимое файла в QString s

        file.close();

        QMessageBox::about(this, FName, s);
    }
```

С записью структуры в файл проблем вроде нет, а с чтением непонятно что делать: как передать содержимое в QString s, так же непонятно как правильно реализовать цикл для записи содержимого файла в QString s

Comment: Используйте QString вместо std::string

Comment: с QString возникает та же ошибка, только для QString, вместо std::string

Comment: Окей, проблема решена, остался вопрос,  как передать вывод из QDataStream stream(...) в QString s

Comment: Всё, разобрался, вопрос решен

Comment: Добавьте решение в ответ, чтобы вопрос не висел неотвеченным

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итоговый правильный вариант

```
#include <QFile>
#include <QDataStream>
#include <QMessageBox>

using namespace std;

const char FName[] = "workers.dat";

struct worker{
    QString wname;
    QString wlastname;
    int wsalary;
};

void MainWindow::on_ReadFilepushButton_clicked()
{
    worker man;
    QString s = "";
    QFile file (FName);
    QDataStream output(&file);
    int i = 0;

    if(file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)){
        while(!output.atEnd()){
            output >> man.wname >> man.wlastname >> man.wsalary;
                i++;
                s += QString::number(i) + ") "
                    + man.wname + " "
                    + man.wlastname + " "
                    + QString::number(man.wsalary) + "\n";
        }

        file.close();

        QMessageBox::about(this, FName, s);
    } else
        QMessageBox::critical(this, FName, "file does not exist");
}
```